# Alias IP Address in VyOS

Tags: nat, ip-address, vyatta, dnat, vyos

I have a network where I am looking to alias an IP address/port and redirect it to another machine.

VyOS is on my network at 192.168.55.1 and I have another device on the network at 192.168.55.66. I would like to redirect all traffic from 192.168.55.1 port 7000 to 192.168.55.66 port 22.

Is this possible?

If it is, would this be a DNAT or an SNAT or some other rule?

If this feature doesn't exactly exist in VyOS, can it be done in general by setting up a Linux box as a router?

Comment: One problem with your NAT is that the traffic must pass through the router for NAT to work, but traffic on the same network doesn't pass through a router. Routers route between networks, not from a network to the same network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a NAT destination rule like

```
Nat destination rule 70
 inbound interface eth0  *change the interface by yours*
 destination 
    address 192.168.551
    port 700
 translation
    address 192.168.55.66
    port 22
```

I never test a destination rule that translate to another IP in the same network but it should work.

I wonder what lead you to such a need, that seems a curious design.

Answer (score 0):

A DNAT rule is used to change the destination of traffic.

Remember for NAT to work you must arrange for replies to go back via the NAT. It may be necessary to use SNAT in combination with DNAT to do this.